# TinyButStrong OpenTBS include output of one template into other Sub Templating

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

we are using TinyButStrong and OpenTbs to prepare word (docx) documents from templates. We basically need to process several sub-templates (based on what user selected) and then merge all as table rows into the main template.

So basically we need something like this:

`Final Template
Table
 Row 1 - Output from docx1 template
 Row 2 - Output from docx2 template`

The rows can vary, so do the sub template file for each individual row.

TBS seems to have a subtpl markup, however its not clear how it takes up arguments especially when we need to tell it which file to use and the parameters for each template to bind with.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to merge two DOCX documents (same for XLSX, PPTX, ...) because of internal elements
 managed automatically by Ms Office (pictures, charts, styles, numbering, ... ).

Internal elements have internal Ids that are different from a DOCX to another DOCX even if they are visually totally equal.

Thus, when you take a piece of content from a first document, its internal Ids are probably discordant with the other document in which you wish to insert it.
When this problem occurs, Ms Office give the message

> We're sorry. We can't open xxxxx.docx because we found a problem with its contents.

The only way to insert an external snippet from a DOCX to another DOCX is to be sure that no internal IDS are used in the snippet.
Such snippets are hard to build.

But the technical to retrieve the snippet from a document is simple. See [GetBlockSource()](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#php_getblocksource)

And and insert it into another is simple too. See [MergeBlock()](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#php_mergeblock) with source type = 'text'.